# DNS for Ingress using in Kubernets Cluster are not working

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

Hi together I am using a kubeadmin Cluster with a master and worker node. I have installd Matallb as Loadbalancer and I am using traefik as ingress. We have to domains booth hase a A-Record to the Node IP. But the DNS in ingress are not working

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dmix-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"

spec:
  rules:
    - host: dev-env.colordigital.cloud
      http: 
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx
                port:
                  number: 80
```

these domain has the same ip like the kubernetes master node.
Can anybody help me how to work with this DNS
dev-env.colordigital.cloud has the same IP like the worker node and
colordigital.cloud has the same IP like the master node where kubernetes is setup.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's really hard to understand your question. Could you please rewrite it? Possible with proper english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the loadbalancer IP for Ingress the same like your DNS